# SWT Table cannot be edited

Tags: swt

I want to use Table to make a table that can be edited all over its cells.
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet88.java
but I can only edit one column each time with the EDITABLECOLUMN

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to edit the `Table`, you should rather use a JFace [`TableViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FTableViewer.html).

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html) is an excellent tutorial on how to use it. Especially the part about [`EditingSupport`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#jfacetable_editor) should be interesting for you.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/TableEditorexample.htm
But I also need to import these data into sqlserver by JDBC.What can I do.Thanks.

Comment: @WorkingBearNoLove You should really use a `TableViewer`. Then you won't have to use such a enormous `Listener`.

Comment: Thanks,It's ok,thoug little strange